# Insert a GIF file in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, gif

I would like to know if it is possible to insert a gif file in latex-beamer without having to split the images first. Most of the answers require the GIF file to be previously breaken down into images. However, I would like to be able to read the .gif file directly from the folder where it is stored (in overleaf).

I am trying to convert the gif file on the fly, with the example code that you see, but it throughs an error to me saying 'file ... not found'

Below have the MWE of the code I am using

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.gif, .ps, .eps, .png}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .gif`-gif-converted-to.png}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Results}
\framesubtitle{Matching set}

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{Figures/GIF/Distrib_of_firms.gif}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

KR

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been able to insert  a .gif in this manner, but I would like to do it directly reading from the .gif file instead from pictures.

Comment: If a `\includegraphics{gif-animation.gif}` solution has not been presented in the abovementioned question, which has been around for more than 5 years with > 130k views, very likely the gif format is not natively supported.
Let me know if it is otherwise.